# UISearchController not dismissing after search

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9, uisearchcontroller, xlform

In iOS9 UISearchController not dismissing after row selection in results controller after performing user filtering in [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm) Objective C Example project for Custom Selectors

Issue with UsersTableViewController.m file
Please check the project file UsersTableViewController.m file

Answer (score 0):

please add this code in search-result controller

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        @try {
            DELog(@"======1viewWillDisappear===== %d",isDisappear);
            if(_searchController!=nil){
                DELog(@"======2viewWillDisappear===== %d",isDisappear);
                _searchController.searchBar.text=@"";
                if ([_searchController isActive]) {
                    DELog(@"======3viewWillDisappear===== %d",isDisappear);
                    [_searchController setActive:NO];
                }

            }

        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
             ERLog(@"Start-Up %@",exception);[[AcraHelper acraHelper] sendError:exception];
        }
    }
```

Comment: no change. I tried this before adding in both didSelect of tableview and ViewWillDisappear

Comment: add   _searchController.searchBar.text=@"";[_searchController setActive:NO]; in viewWillDisappear of search page  as well as search result page